# programmatically defined button list with notification

Tags: ios, uibutton

**update 1**

When each button is tapped by the user, I want the first letter of the card's suit (S,H,D, or C) and the card's name (A, K, Q, J, or T) to be added to the list of cards, an NSMutableArray named "cards". So, for example, if the Ace of Diamonds button is tapped, I want `@"DA"` to be added to "cards" and the button to be disabled.

In order not to have 52 separate methods, one for each card of the deck, I think I need to register for a distinct NSNotification in each button. If that is correct then, I would like to know **how to create the argument for `addObserver:... selector:selector() ...` as a parameter.** None of the examples I have seen show how to create a parameter like "cardDA" within the parens for `selector()`.

**update 1**

**update 0**

[This answer seems to be what I need (for now)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427074/programmatically-adding-a-view-with-a-button?rq=1)

**update 0**

I want to create an array of buttons that individually represent the 52 cards of a bridge card deck. The buttons will be arranged in two subarrays, one for the 5 "honors" Ace, King, ... , 10, and one for the other 8 other cards of each suit. After each button is touched, I want its card ID or the whole button to disappear but for the array to remain in its original position. When all the buttons are touched, the task is done.

[This answer shows how to programmatically create UITextFields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060578/), but UIButtons do not seem to play well with iOS `frames` and `CGRects`, so I am having trouble adapting that answer to my case.

[This answer suggests using UIActionSheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273939/) but they do not seem flexible enough for my needs, either.

The attached image suggests the Honors buttons array part of the View.

[image]

Comment: Not a question. More like a meditation, really.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing I was missing was that `currentTitle` can be used to determine the title of the button in the action method to which it is sent. Now I only need 4 button creator methods; one for Spades, one for Hearts, ... Diamonds, Clubs.

`NSString *card = [sender currentTitle];`

I am sorry I could not express the question so that anyone understood it.

Next I am going to learn how to disable a tapped button, hopefully.